# php - Previous page redirection after login (security)

Tags: php, html, redirect, authentication

I have a php application which redirects to the login page if the session is timed out.
I'd like the login page to redirect the user to his previous location once relogged.
Ideally the user would recover even his complete request.
I thought of encoding the whole request within the login form like:

```
<input name="previous_request"
  value="<?php base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($_REQUEST))) ?>" />
```

But not sure if it's very secure or if it is advised.
I'm wondering what are the best practices for that.
Is is a common practice to serialize the entire request for the "relogging" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done so
   When the user is redirected to reloging, as you said serialize $ _REQUEST will write it into the database and the page will send its md5. So I think it will be safer

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a good solution. But finally I will keep only the previous url. The question was more about the "practiceness"

Comment: regarding the practicality of your proposed method @pierreDeLEspinay, i dont really see a problem with saving the entire request.  after all, you want to make the relogging as seamless as possible for the user.  UNLESS you have so serious a security issue (like online banking), where NO state should be saved at all.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use $_REQUEST see [here](http://devlog.info/2010/02/04/why-php-request-array-is-dangerous/) for details.

Instead, just start a `session` and when the user times out, and logs back in, send him back to the page which is stored in the `session`.

You could store this into the session:

```
"http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Or, if using https you could check if the `$_SERVER['PORT']` is 443, and apply that to your code.

Comment: You mean store the previous url in a session variable ?

Comment: @Glide well yes, when a user navigates to another webpage, the session will be updated. When the timeout occures, the session won't be updated obviously and after a succesful login you will redirect him to the page by reading the session information.